# ColdFusion Variable Deleting Table Contents

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am currently working in a Cold Fusion site that is several years old and have been tasked with modifying the functionality in several different areas. So far things have been going alright but I came across one particular area of the code that I have no idea what it does and its baffling to me. I've searched online related to it and haven't found anything either. This is one of the weirdest statements I've ever seen. Perhaps its just my inexperience to CF but not sure.

There's a particular variable or special statement that seems like its deleting all rows from a certain DB table but I've ran this same process several times and there are still rows in the table afterwards. I want all rows to be deleted, and could re-write easily but I want to understand what is currently going on and if this is some kind of CF functionality that is supposed to do this for me.

Below is the code statement that looks like a cfset but not really.

```
<CF_SQLDelete table="temporary_employee_table" datasource="#gDSN_Name#">
```

We are currently running CF 11 on our server but I know this website was originally written 10+ years ago so there may be partial things left over from previous versions of CF. So I'm kind of wanting to ask the CF and Stack Overflow community if they've ever seen anything like this before. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd greatly appreciated it!

Comment: When it starts with cf and an underscore it's a so called custom tag. Somewhere there's a file `sqldelete.cfm`

Comment: Run the page with debugging on and you will see the path to the file.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. I eventual found the file in suspect and was able to examine its contents!. Found it by going into the CF Administrator->Extensions->Custom Tag Paths. This gave me the directory where custom tags and files are stored on the server.